# Ajax not working in mobile, what is missing?

Tags: jquery

I used the solution on this page - https://scripthere.com/simple-infinite-scroll-for-wordpress-sites-without-plugin/ to run infinite scroll on my blog. In the desktop version everything works as it should, unfortunately in the mobile version it does not work at all. I am asking for help in locating the problem.

This is what the script looks like in a separate file:

```
jQuery.noConflict($);
/* Ajax functions */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //find scroll position
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        //init
        var that = $('#loadMore');
        var page = $('#loadMore').data('page');
        var newPage = page + 1;
        var ajaxurl = $('#loadMore').data('url');
        //check
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

            //ajax call
            $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    page: page,
                    action: 'ajax_script_load_more'
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                success: function(response) {
                    //check
                    if (response == 0) {
                        //check
                        if ($("#no-more").length == 0) {
                            $('#ajax-content').append('<div id="no-more" class="text-center"><h3>You reached the end of the line!</h3><p>No more posts to load.</p></div>');
                        }
                        $('#loadMore').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#loadMore').data('page', newPage);
                        $('#ajax-content').append(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Every browser's engine used to have different implementation on [this w3c spec about inner or client boxing calculation](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/). But, I'd assume this is not the case anymore. I'd suggest you to create a HTML element for debugging purpose in mobile and print out the values of those `innerHeight`s and see where it went wrong. Well, for sure that `==` is the culprit, but may be better to know to start from there.

Comment: Any error is happening? Or nothing happens?

Comment: try adding  $.ajax{cache:false}

Comment: Vinicius Lima - nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

add this metadata with: height=device-height

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```

try adding new event touchmove + ajax cache: false and ajax method:"POST" for old version JQ.

```
            $(window).scroll(onScroll);
            //$(document.body).on('touchmove', onScroll); // for mobile
            function onScroll() {
                var that = $('#loadMore');
                var page = $('#loadMore').data('page');
                var newPage = page + 1;
                var ajaxurl = $('#loadMore').data('url');
                var mobile = 56 + 'px';
                //check
                if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

                    //ajax call
                    $.ajax({
                        cache:false,
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        type: 'post',
                        method:"POST",
                        data: {
                            page: page,
                            action: 'ajax_script_load_more'
                        },
                        error: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        success: function (response) {
                            //check
                            if (response == 0) {
                                //check
                                if ($("#no-more").length == 0) {
                                    $('#ajax-content').append('<div id="no-more" class="text-center"><h3>You reached the end of the line!</h3><p>No more posts to load.</p></div>');
                                }
                                $('#loadMore').hide();
                            } else {
                                $('#loadMore').data('page', newPage);
                                $('#ajax-content').append(response);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: One question: On mobile device the function onScroll() is called by event on scroll or touchmove?